# In Groovy Language How to replace a character in a string based on the value and position in the string

Tags: string, groovy, soapui

I am looking to amend the values of a string IF certain positions within a string are certain values for example I have a postcode L65 OBH and I need to do the following:

(1)

If the 1st value in the first section of the string (split by white space) = L it needs to be changed to T. This would then give:

T65 OBH

(2)

Then if the 2nd value in the first section of the string (split by white space) = 6 it needs to be changed to 7. This would then give:

T75 OBH

(3)

Then if the 1st value in the second section of the string (split by white space) = O it needs to be changed to 2. This would then give:

T75 2BH

(4)

Then if the 3rd value in the second section of the string (split by white space) = H it needs to be changed to P. This would then give:

T75 2BP

I'm assuming that I need to use replaceall and a number of IF statements but I am struggling to work this out, particularly how to split the 2 different parts of the postcode out treat them as separate enteties....can anyone help please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write a helper method for the replacement rules:

```
def postcode = 'L65 0BH'

def (first, second) = postcode.split(/\s+/)

def replaceIf(String token, int position, String match, String replacement) {
    (0..<token.length()).collect { index ->
        if(index == position && token[index] == match) {
            replacement
        }
        else {
            token[index]
        }
    }.join()
}

first = replaceIf(first, 0, 'L', 'T')
first = replaceIf(first, 1, '6', '7')
second = replaceIf(second, 0, '0', '2')
second = replaceIf(second, 2, 'H', 'P')

assert "$first $second" == 'T75 2BP'
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick feedback tim_yates this looks to be what I want to use however it gives me 2BP as a response?

Comment: You need to join the two together `"$first $second"` as I show at the bottom of my code

Answer (score 0):

```
def strVal= "L65 OBH"
strVal.replaceFirst(/^L/, "T")

def strVal1= "L65 OBH"
strVal1.replaceFirst(/^6/, "7")
```

and so on using the same `replaceFirst()` method